# How is it possible to set memory limit for a ( scheduled ) command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to run scheduled commands, so I added them to the `schedule` method of my `ConsoleKernel`.
It runs, but I get an error:

```
Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ... bytes)
```

If I add an `ini_set('memory_limit','256M')` to the `handle` method of my command, then it works without error.

Is there a better way to increase the memory limit for a command?

Comment: `php -d memory_limit=256M artisan schedule:run`

Comment: @Saman That will not work, because the scheduler runs each command in a new process with `shell_exec`

Comment: If you need to use `$schedule->command` just add `php -d memory_limit=256M` before your command; otherwise, Laravel handles commands in one shell.

Comment: Just add it to the global php.ini.